# Format parameters in rasql encode() are not parsed correctly

Tags: rasdaman

I send a query to rasql

```
ssh servername "rasql -q 'select encode(r[43:44,43:45],\"tiff\",\"{\"geoReference\":{\"crs   \":\"EPSG:4623\"}}\") from myCollection as r'  --out file --outfile filename
```

and I get parsing error:

```
rasdaman error 300: Parsing error 300 in line 1, column 40: Unexpected name geoReference
```

any parameter given this way to encode() is treated like this.
so, what's wrong with my " \ {} etc here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a shell escaping issue, if you try to execute this directly on the server and not via ssh it should work fine:

```
rasql -q 'select encode(r[43:44,43:45],"tiff","{\"geoReference\":{\"crs   \":\"EPSG:4623\"}}") from myCollection as r'  --out file --outfile filename
```

If you notice, the double quotes inside the format parameter string already need to be escaped. So if you execute this command via ssh, you need to double escape those `\"`, something like this:

```
ssh servername "rasql -q 'select encode(r[43:44,43:45],\"tiff\",\"{\\\"geoReference\\\":{\\\"crs\\\":\\\"EPSG:4623\\\"}}\") from myCollection as r' --out file --outfile filename
```